# Как проверить все checkbox и если value = 1 , то сделать checked?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Есть условие, что у чекбоксов не заданы классы,нужно ссылаться только на тип и value

Нужен чистый js,сам я чайник в нем,да и не понимаю, как ссылаться на тип

Вот то, что сейчас есть, но увы работает только для 1-го чекбокса

```
var sd = document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]');    

if (sd.value == 1) {
   sd.checked = true; 
}
```

Заранее спасибо большое за помощь)

Comment: value у чего? Можете привести свое решение на jQuery, а мы переведем на чистый JS

Comment: с jQuery могу написать, если есть класс, а мне нужен код на js, который я буду вписывать в консоль через браузер

Comment: Напишите с классом. Мы уберем класс

Comment: Нашел, как это можно реализовать через js,теперь вопрос, как сделать,чтобы работало не только для 1-го чекбокса

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll`

Comment: не сработало,когда я заменил на document.querySelectorAll,как я понял, нужно создавать массив для всех этих чекбоксов со значением 1, а потом делать их checked?

Comment: @АлексейМилюков уверены ли вы, что применили его [правильно](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)? И, пожалуйста, предоставьте ваши попытки получить желаемое в коде. Мы не можем узнать, что "не сработало" не увидев код

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelector` возвращает один элемент, первый который подходит под условия селектора. Вам нужен `document.querySelectorAll` который вернет коллекцию, и можно перебрать циклом

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" value="1">

<script>
  var checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
  var i = 0;

  for (; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
    var check = checkbox[i];

    if (check.value === '1') {
        check.checked = true;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за объяснения,все очень понятно, ранее никогда с этим не работал)

Comment: @АлексейМилюков тут есть один неявный момент, `querySelectorAll` возвращает не совсем массив, а коллекцию которая похожа не массив, но таковой не является https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/NodeList ссылочка для справки

Comment: Есть смысл в написании `var i = 0` вне цикла? Чтобы не париться с i и проще получать текуший элемент итерации можно использовать `for of` или `forEach`. Также как Вам идея чтобы использовать селектор `input[type=checkbox][value="1"]`?

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько `var i` вне цикла это просто мой стиль написания кода, привычка. Все переменный которые используются в некой блочной зоне определяются в самом ее верху. Пример просто демонстративный, конечно `forEach` лучше, я забыл про него, раньше у нод-коллекций не было метода forEach.

Answer (score 0):

Написал на скорую руку используя **ES5** надеюсь никто ничего против не имеет.

```js
function toggle(source) {
  checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]'); 
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /> Toggle All<br/>

<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar1"> Bar 1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar2"> Bar 2<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar3"> Bar 3<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar4"> Bar 4<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Получаем список чекбоксов при помощи `document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');`
2. У списка вызываем метод `forEach` и перебираем все элементы списка

```js
function setCheck() {
  const items = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
  items.forEach(function(el) {
    if (el.value == 1) {
      el.checked = true;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" value="1" />
<button onclick="setCheck()">Check</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто через селектор `[value="1"]`

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox][value="1"]')

for (el of items) {
  el.checked = true
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" value="1">
```